# How to stop a playing sound using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound in ios7?

Tags: audio, ios7

I am playing the custom sound in my application using AudioServicesPlaySystemSound,how can i stop the sound immediately when i touch any button.
currently i am using the below code to stop the sound but its not work well

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesRemoveSystemSoundCompletion (soundID);
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(soundID);
```

Comment: Yes finally i got it works. SystemSoundID soundID has be to declare as global then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the System Sound Services, you can use the [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Chapters/Reference.html), it doesn't require any outside support library and overall easy to implement. See some [implementation examples here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/69369/audio-tutorial-ios-playing-audio-programatically-2014-edition).

Comment: Thanks, Whether AVAudioPlayer will work in background?

Comment: Yes, it will work the same way. Look through the implementation example in the link.